# Unexpected datetime differencing with Python 3

Tags: python, datetime

I am using Python 3 - Linux Rocky 8. I am not getting the expected results when subtracting datetime objects.

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('11 Nov 2022 17:36', '%d %b %Y %H:%M')
y = datetime.datetime.strptime('10 Nov 2022 17:30', '%d %b %Y %H:%M')
z = (x - y).seconds
print(str(z))
360

y = datetime.datetime.strptime('10 Nov 2022 17:40', '%d %b %Y %H:%M')
z = (x - y).seconds
print(str(z))
86160
```

I thought the time differences would 1 day + 6 minutes and 1 day - 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the `.seconds` attribute of a `timedelta` object. Not the **total** seconds

Look at `x - y` directly. In the first case.

```
datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=360)
```

In the second

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=86160)
```

The `seconds` attribute will never be negative, and you do not have a full day.

Perhaps you wanted `print(z.total_seconds())`